# Gradle Dependencies library empty after project is moved

Tags: java, git, gradle, libgdx

I have a libGDX project on one computer in Eclipse, using the Gradle plugin and EGit to sync the project to github. On another computer, when I clone the repo in eclipse with EGit the project loads but the "Gradle Dependencies" library in the package explorer is no longer there, and I get errors everywhere that I import from the gdx library.

When I go to *Project -> properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries* I see the "Gradle Dependencies" library above the "JRE System Library" (which does show up in the package explorer), but this "Gradle Dependencies" library is empty on the new computer but has all of the depended java files on the original computer. I think it is a problem with my build.gradle file, which was automatically generated using the libgdx project generator, but adding this to my build.gradle didn't fix anything:

```
dependencies{
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:1.6"
}
```

[full build.gradle in the -core project](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/USim2k15/University-Simulator/2cd985bb316621a158172df19929d4e9716ef57d/University%20Sim%202k15-core/build.gradle)

[full build.gradle in the -desktop project](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/USim2k15/University-Simulator/2cd985bb316621a158172df19929d4e9716ef57d/University%20Sim%202k15-desktop/build.gradle)

Question: How does the build.gradle file find the Gradle Dependencies library? Why did it find the dependencies on the original computer but not the new one?

Comment: does your build.gradle not have a `repositories` section?

Comment: It doesn't, and I'm not sure why. Could the libgdx project generator have generated it improperly?

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with libgdx project generator, but speaking in general about how gradle handles dependencies:

the build.gradle file usually contains a repositories section of the form:

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  mavenLocal()
}
```

When you declare dependencies in the `dependencies` section, gradle looks for dependencies in declared repositories, in the order that they appear. If needed, the corrected versions of dependencies are downloaded into gradle local cache and will show up in your ecplise build-path as well.

I suggest you add a repositories section to your build.gradle file and run 
`gradle build --refresh-dependencies` from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

If you moved your project into another directory, Gradle needs to refresh its cache. Just right click in the Gradle pane and select "Refresh Gradle project".